# Java - How can i avoid NullPointerException when i read an empty file

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

i have class **Customer** and **array list of Customer**

and i have a method to read the objects form the Customers' File and add them to the array list

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public void readFile(File customerFile) throws IOException, NullPointerException {
    ObjectInputStream OIS = null;

    try {
        FileInputStream FIS = new FileInputStream(customerFile);
        OIS = new ObjectInputStream(FIS);

        Customer customerObj = null;

        while (true) {
            customerObj = (Customer) OIS.readObject();
            this.customerList.add(customerObj);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("(Exception : " + ex.toString() + ")");
    } finally {
        OIS.close();
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            Print(); // print the customerList
        } else {
            System.out.println("The Customer List Is Empty !");
        }
    }
}
```

So can any one help me?

NullPointerException at `OIS.close();`

Comment: `FileName.length()==0` Check this condition for empty files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code like this:

```
public void readFile(File customerFile) throws IOException, NullPointerException {
    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(customerFile))) {
        Customer customerObj = null;

        while (true) {
            customerObj = (Customer) ois.readObject();
            this.customerList.add(customerObj);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("(Exception : " + ex.toString() + ")");
    }

    if (!isEmpty()) {
        Print(); // print the customerList
    } else {
        System.out.println("The Customer List Is Empty !");
    }
}
```

In my code I'm using `try-with-resources` statement. It will automatically close your `InputStream`.